# Uninstalling GDB on a Mac

Tags: macintosh, gdb

I'm having lots of problems with GDB; usually crashes and starts using 100% CPU until I kill the process using the activity monitor on the Mac (using Mavericks).

How do I remove GDB from my machine (using GDB 7.6.1)? I plan to install an older version (GDB 6.x.x) after uninstalling this version.

Comment: which gdb returns /usr/local/bin/gdb. I used this to install it http://panks.me/blog/2013/11/install-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks-from-source/

Comment: I compiled the source code(unpacked the .tar file ./configure and  compiled the source code using make), and did sudo make install.

Comment: yup bin, include lib, share

Comment: I dont thnik so. most of the directories contain about 5 heaser files thats about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to simply remove whole `/usr/local` in case you haven't installed anything else there (according to out little detour in comments, I think that is the case). So `sudo mv /usr/local /usr/_local` will get rid of whatever gunk is there (you can delete the directory later, when you're sure it contains nothing important).

Then instead of following the path of building gdb from scratch, use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install gdb. If this doesn't work as expected either, then just `mv /usr/local /usr/__local` (or something similar, I think you can see the pattern to emerge here) and try building an older version from source. I'd still recommend that you at least try homebrew bottled version, because gdb 6 is quite aged already.

Comment: thanks mate..in order the bin directory containd only gdb inside it.and lnclude lib contains ansidecl.h bfdlink.h gdb
bfd.h  dis-asm.h symcat.h and share contains gdb info locale man

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, GDB doesn't have a top-level uninstaller.

There is a way to get much the same effect, though. Starting from within the directory where you unpacked the GDB source code:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/doomed-gdb
$ make && make install
$ cd $HOME/doomed-gdb
$ sudo find . -type f -exec rm /usr/local/{} \;
```

Nothing should be left which could interfere with a different GDB installed afterward.

Comment: Clever. What if any of the files where already there before GDB installation? :-)

Comment: @Danijel: They were already overwritten by the initial installation. The command above will give you a list of files to restore from your backups.

Comment: They may be overwritten, but can they be removed? Maybe other app was using them. Overwrite may have just been an update.

Comment: @Danijel: That’s a new situation. OP said he’s installing an older version after uninstalling this version.

Comment: I mistakenly deleted just the gdb folder you get when you extract the tar from the official download of GDB. I still had some files around /usr/local of course. Reinstalling it with your first 2 lines and then deleting it with the last 2 lines you suggested I erased any entry/remaining file in the /usr/local directory: Thank you! :)

Comment: Now installing gdb using home-brew @WarrenYoung